# catalyst can't forward to private action

Tags: perl, action, private, catalyst, forward

In [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) I'm trying to forward to a private action to do some work. Here is the function definition:

```
sub get_form :Private :Args(1) {
  my ($self, $c, $type_id) = @_;
  #do stuff
}
```

I try to forward to it like so:

```
$c->forward('get_form',[$type_id]);
```

But it just gives me this error:

```
Couldn't forward to command "get_form": Invalid action or component.
```

However, if I change the action from `:Private` to `:Local`, then it works. Does anyone know why this is and how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need rather can't use `:Args(1)` for private actions in Catalyst.

[From cpan Catalyst Manual](http://search.cpan.org/~hkclark/Catalyst-Manual-5.9006/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Intro.pod#Flow_Control):
You can pass new arguments to a forward action by adding them in an anonymous array. In the called method(or forwarded method), you would get arguments in `$c->req->args`.

```
sub hello : Global {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
    $c->stash->{message} = 'Hello World!';
    $c->forward('check_message',[qw/test1/]);
}

sub check_message : Private {
    my ( $self, $c, $first_argument ) = @_;
    my $also_first_argument = $c->req->args->[0]; # now = 'test1'
    # do something...
}
```

You can also use stash `$c->stash->{typeid};` instead. Then you can directly call the method using `$c->forward('priv_method');`.

Ex:

```
   sub hello : Global {
        my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
        $c->stash->{message} = 'Hello World!';
        $c->forward('check_message'); # $c is automatically included
    }

    sub check_message : Private {
        my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
        return unless $c->stash->{message};
        $c->forward('show_message');
    }

    sub show_message : Private {
        my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
        $c->res->body( $c->stash->{message} );
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also avoid forward() at all if you wish and just call the method if it's the same controller:

```
sub myaction : Global {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
    $self->dosomething( $c, 'mystring' );
}

sub dosomething {
    my ( $self, $c, $argument ) = @_;
    $c->log->info( $argument );
}
```

Even though you have to pass `$c` around, this can often be an easier to read approach.

Answer (score 4):

If I were to guess, it's because you are telling to match certain urls (`:Args(1)`), but `:Private` "will never match a URL". "Catalyst's `:Private` attribute is exclusive and doesn't work with other attributes". Try passing info via the context object instead.